# Unable to process dict properly

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have dict which got list, what I want is to display list elements in one line.

My dict

```
data = {'id':[1,2], 'name':['foo','bar'], 'type':['x','y']}
```

Expected output

```
   name is foo and id is 1
   name is bar and id is 2
```

My code

```
>>> data = {'id':[1,2], 'name':['foo','bar'], 'type':['x','y']}
>>> for key, value in data.items():
...     print(value)
... 
['foo', 'bar']
['x', 'y']
[1, 2]
>>>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to iterate through two lists in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-to-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel)

Comment: Your code just prints the `value`, and that is what you got. You say you expect 
 `name is foo and id is 1`

but your code does not have the strings "name is", nor "and id is"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `zip()` as:

```
for name, idx in zip(data['name'], data['id']):
    print(f"name is {name} and id is {idx}")
```

Use `format()` if you are using python version lower than 3.6:

```
for name, idx in zip(data['name'], data['id']):
    print("name is {0} and id is {1}".format(name, idx))
```

Comment: '''print(f"name is {name} and id is {id}")
                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax'''

Comment: looks good to me, is your python version < 3.6 in which case `f-strings` might not be supported and you can use `format()`